# Control over trac TicketQuery: Is it possible to change the ticket color according to its priority?

Tags: report, trac

I am configuring a trac installation (ver 0.12) at the moment and I am trying to make the startingpage a bit more talkative.

In the report module of trac it was possible to change the backgroundcolor of a ticket according to its priority using SQL as described [here](http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/7199), but I did not find any information on how to change it in the TicketQuery macro.

Can anybody give me a hint?

regards, Chris

Comment: When you mention the TicketQuery Macro do you mean the [TracQuery](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracQuery), [Custom Query](http://trac.edgewall.org/query) or the [report module](http://trac.edgewall.org/report)? If you mean the report module, then you can look at the documentation [here](https://trac.ppiatm.com:777/trac/QAReporter/wiki/TracReports#Customformattingcolumns) and see how to set up row color based on an integer between 1 and 5. Trac uses this to tie to the tickets priority. If that is too limiting, you can also use Trac's column formatter, `__style__` , for setting specific styels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colors are defined by CSS classes in *report.css* of Trac core for ticket tables generated by reports, custom query and the TicketQueryMacro.
So you can only change this site-wide in Trac 0.12 by adding [custom styles](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/CookBook/SiteStyleCss).

The appropriate CSS statements to add to your own *style.css* are (with default values):

- table.tickets tbody tr.prio1 { background: #FFDDCC none repeat scroll 0 0 }
- table.tickets tbody tr.even.prio1 { background: #FFEEDD none repeat scroll 0 0 }
- table.tickets tbody tr.prio2 { background: #FFFFBB none repeat scroll 0 0 }
- table.tickets tbody tr.even.prio2 { background: #FFFFDD none repeat scroll 0 0 }
- table.tickets tbody tr.prio3 { background: #FBFBFB none repeat scroll 0 0 }
- table.tickets tbody tr.even.prio3 { background: #F6F6F6 none repeat scroll 0 0 }
- table.tickets tbody tr.prio4 { background: #E7FFFF none repeat scroll 0 0 }
- table.tickets tbody tr.even.prio4 { background: #DDFFFF none repeat scroll 0 0 }
- table.tickets tbody tr.prio5 { background: #E7EEFF none repeat scroll 0 0 }
- table.tickets tbody tr.even.prio5 { background: #DDE7FF none repeat scroll 0 0 }
- table.tickets tbody tr.prio6 { background: #F0F0F0 none repeat scroll 0 0 }
- table.tickets tbody tr.even.prio6 { background: #F7F7F7 none repeat scroll 0 0 }

These max 6 prio's corresponding to slightly different odd/even row color each ranging from red over grey to blue. Only 5 prio's are used per default, prio6 defaults are in darker gray again.

*Order matters*, make sure to have your priority names properly sorted in the priority admin panel (`http://<host>:<port>/<env>/admin/ticket/priority`).